# System.Exception, xUnit calling HttpDelete action on the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, xunit, web-api-testing

I'm getting "*System.Exception : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.*" when I'm calling:

```
  var result = controllerApi.DeleteCliente(2);
```

**the DeleteCliente code (inside the controller):**

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "PaginaDeClientes")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult DeleteCliente(int clienteId)
        {
            var cliente = _context.Clientes.Find(clienteId);

            if (cliente == null) { return NotFound(); }

            _context.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
            var result =  _context.SaveChanges();
            if (result <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

**My test  DeleteCliente():**

```
   [Fact]
        public void DeleteCliente()
        {
            var controllerApi = new PoollGest.Controllers.Api.ClientesController(_context);
            _context.Clientes.Add(new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = 2,
                Nome = "Jose",
                Desconto = 20,
            });
            var result = controllerApi.DeleteCliente(2);
            Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
        }
```

This controller currently only has the deleteCliente action, for reference I have run other tests where I create an object in my context and run one of the "crud" action's and I had no problems, not sure what I'm doing wrong here

**Error:**
[image: error]

Comment: Can you run your test in the debugger? Set a breakpoint at _context.SaveChanges() and step into the method to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact cause of the problem when I run the debug with the breakpoints, but it works now.
I Basically rebuild the entire project, deleted the migrations, build the bd again. And it works now, so if you have a similar problem I recommend you to rebuild your project.

[image: fix]